# Зашить в приложение SSL сертификат

Tags: android, https, ssl

Возможно ли вшить в приложение самоподписанный сертификат ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы включить в приложение "нестандартные" ресурсы существует специальная папка `assets`. Поместите в неё файл сертификата и при работе приложения загружайте его оттуда.

В интернете можно даже найти примеры реализации. Например, [тут](http://my-it-notes.com/2011/09/how-to-approve-ssl-certificate-on-android/).